# perl: How to trim a certail part of a string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this value stored in a string

```
"-rw-rw-r--  1 xyz test   3.7K Mar 25 14:59 abcd.txt".
```

And i just want to trim the `"abcd.txt"` part from the string into another.

**NB - rest of the part is not constant.**

Comment: Split the string into a list based on the " " separator and then take the last element of the list.

Comment: The filename might have space.

Comment: no, there is not space in the file name

Comment: Finally this code helped me.. :)

`my @array2 = split(/\s+/,$array1);`
`my $last = pop(@array2);`

Comment: Then what you probably want is `my $last = (split /\s+/, $array1)[-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my ($trimmed) = $string =~ /(\S+)$/;
```

although you might be better with using ie. `glob("*txt")` rather than fiddling with external `ls`.

[perldoc -f glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)

Comment: Filename might have space.

Comment: @Pradeep, use `glob()`

Comment: Right, that's the best & correct way, but I was suggesting about the regex.

Comment: @Pradeep regex depend on `ls` output which may change, or is different on some platforms, not to mention forking of another process for such trivial task.

Comment: +1 for suggesting glob, in addition to answering the question (literally)

Comment: @mpapec , thanks for the suggestion, but i only want the **last file in the list**. will i be able to do that too??

Answer (score 0):

```
($filename) = $string =~ /\d\s(.+?)$/
```